# How to choose initial point of root finding algorithm?

Tags: systems-of-equations, physics, nonlinear-system, computational-mathematics

I want to solve the following system of non-linear equations:

[image]

That is, three equations in two unknowns ($x$ and $y$).

These, of course, describe hyperbola. The solution, as I understand it, involves the intersection of hyperbola. I want to solve this using the GNU Scientific Library's multi-root finder (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/multiroots.html). This requires that I choose some initial point for the root finder. How do I go about determining an initial point?

Comment: @Moo All values are known, with the exception of $x$ and $y$. This system is the solution to a localization problem (the Time Difference of Arrival Multilateration problem), where $x_i,y_i$ is the known location of some observer, $t_i$ is the time of arrival at that observer, and $s$ is the speed of some signal.

Comment: Since this involved three circles with known centers, the unbiased estimate (ignoring any information in the $s$ and $t_i$ variables) could just be the center of the incircle of the triangle with vertices fixed at the 3 centers.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar I'm not entirely sure I'm following. I understand somewhat what you mean, but what if the source is outside of the triangle formed by the three observers (as, in my case, I know it to be)?

Comment: The last equation looks like it should have $s(t_1-t_3)$ instead.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Oh, yes, that's correct! I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_i=\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}$ be the radius and $\hat r_i=r_i-st_i,~r_i=\hat r_i+st_i$ be the "shifted radius" of the circle centered at $(x_i,y_i)$ with $(x,y)$ on its edge. We can interpret the problem as finding the point where all shifted radii are equal. A decent and simple initial estimate may be to use the average of $(x_i,y_i)$.

It's worth noting that it is very easy to algebraically solve for $r_i$. This then boils the problem down to [circle-circle intersection](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html).